# kuberntes ingress aws deployment loadbalancer pending

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-elb, kubernetes-ingress

In brief,These are the steps I have done :

1. Launched **2** new `t3 - small` instances in aws, pre-tagged with key
   `kubernetes.io/cluster/<cluster-name>` and value `member`.
2. Tagged the new security with same tag and opened all ports mentioned
   here -
   https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports
3. Changed `hostname` to the output of `curl
   http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname` and verified
   with `hostnamectl`
4. Rebooted
5. Configured aws with
   `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html`
6. Created `IAM role` with full (`"*"`) permissions and assigned to EC2
   instances.
7. Installed `kubelet kubeadm kubectl` using `apt-get`
8. Created `/etc/default/kubelet` with content
   `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cloud-provider=aws`
9. Ran `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` on one instance
   and used output to `kubeadm join ...` other node.
10. Installed [Helm](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-software-on-kubernetes-clusters-with-the-helm-package-manager).
11. Installed [ingress controller](https://akomljen.com/aws-cost-savings-by-utilizing-kubernetes-ingress-with-classic-elb/) with default backend.

Previously I have tried the above steps, but, installed ingress from the instructions on [kubernetes.github.io](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws). Both ended up with same status, `EXTERNAL-IP` as `<pending>`.

---

Current status is :

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                                   IP              NODE                                           
ingress       ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-77d989fb4d-qz4f5                      10.244.1.13     ip-YYY-YY-Y-YYY.ap-south-1.compute.internal               
ingress       ingress-nginx-ingress-default-backend-7f7bf55777-dhj75                 10.244.1.12     ip-YYY-YY-Y-YYY.ap-south-1.compute.internal               
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-bklt8                                               10.244.1.14     ip-YYY-YY-Y-YYY.ap-south-1.compute.internal               
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-ftn8q                                               10.244.1.16     ip-YYY-YY-Y-YYY.ap-south-1.compute.internal               
kube-system   etcd-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.internal                      172.31.12.119   ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.internal              
kube-system   kube-apiserver-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.internal            172.31.12.119   ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.internal              
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.internal   172.31.12.119   ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.internal              
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-87k8p                                            172.31.12.119   ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.internal              
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-f4wft                                            172.31.3.106    ip-YYY-YY-Y-YYY.ap-south-1.compute.internal               
kube-system   kube-proxy-79cp2                                                       172.31.3.106    ip-YYY-YY-Y-YYY.ap-south-1.compute.internal               
kube-system   kube-proxy-sv7md                                                       172.31.12.119   ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.internal              
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.internal            172.31.12.119   ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-south-1.compute.internal              
kube-system   tiller-deploy-5b7c66d59c-fgwcp                                         10.244.1.15     ip-YYY-YY-Y-YYY.ap-south-1.compute.internal
```

`kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE   SELECTOR
default       kubernetes                              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      73m   <none>
ingress       ingress-nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.97.167.197    <pending>     80:32722/TCP,443:30374/TCP   59m   app=nginx-ingress,component=controller,release=ingress
ingress       ingress-nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.109.198.179   <none>        80/TCP                       59m   app=nginx-ingress,component=default-backend,release=ingress
kube-system   kube-dns                                ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP                73m   k8s-app=kube-dns
kube-system   tiller-deploy                           ClusterIP      10.96.216.119    <none>        44134/TCP                    67m   app=helm,name=tiller
```

---

```
kubectl describe service -n ingress ingress-nginx-ingress-controller
Name:                     ingress-nginx-ingress-controller
Namespace:                ingress
Labels:                   app=nginx-ingress
                          chart=nginx-ingress-1.4.0
                          component=controller
                          heritage=Tiller
                          release=ingress
Annotations:              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: *
Selector:                 app=nginx-ingress,component=controller,release=ingress
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.104.55.18
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32318/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.20:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  32560/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.20:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

attached IAM role inline policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

kubectl get nodes -o wide

```
NAME                                           STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
ip-172-31-12-119.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Ready    master   6d19h   v1.13.4   172.31.12.119   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.4.0-1077-aws   docker://18.6.3
ip-172-31-3-106.ap-south-1.compute.internal    Ready    <none>   6d19h   v1.13.4   172.31.3.106    XX.XXX.XX.XXX   Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.4.0-1077-aws   docker://18.6.3
```

---

Could someone please point out what am I missing here, as everywhere on the internet it says a `Classic ELB` will be deployed automatically ?

Comment: Do `kubectl describe service ingress-nginx-ingress-controller`. The reason for why it's stuck in `pending` is normally listed under `events`.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Updated question, no events.

Comment: Hmm is this a public load balancer? Do your vpc subnets have the right k8s tags? (key `kubernetes.io/role/elb` value `1` for public and `kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb`, `1` for private subnets)?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I need a public load balancer, just added `../role/elb` tag to the existing subnet. What to do next? I wonder where these things are documented!

Comment: Delete the service and redeploy, see if it helps. Make sure all public subnets have that `kubernetes.io/role/elb` tag.

Comment: yes, tried it. nothing happened. still in `pending` state. Were you installing `ingress` using `Helm` like in the blog I mentioned?

Comment: @KrIsHnA what does `kubectl cluster-info dump | grep LoadBalancer` show?

Comment: @KrIsHnA You must have the --cloud-provider=aws flag added to the Kubelet before adding the node to the cluster.

Comment: @A_Suh Binary file (standard input) matches

Comment: @A_Suh are you talking about the `step 8` in the question? If not please tell me how to do.

Comment: no roles assigned to worker node, any problem with that? details added.

Comment: @KrIsHnA change every --cloud-provider to be --cloud-provider=aws (or add if missing) in the following files:
**kubelet.service** , **kube-apiserver.service** , **kube-controller-manager.service**. Once done,  1) Restart the daemon (sudo systemctl daemon-reload) 
2) restart the service e.g. (sudo systemctl restart kubelet)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190819/discussion-between-a-suh-and-krishna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AWS ELB (type Classic) you have to

1. Explicitly specify `--cloud-provider=aws` in kube services manifests
   located in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` on the master node:

   `kube-controller-manager.yaml
    kube-apiserver.yaml`
2. Restart services:

   `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

   `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`

---

Along with other commands, add at bottom or top as you wish. The result should be similar to :

in *kube-controller-manager.yaml*

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --cloud-provider=aws
```

in *kube-apiserver.yaml*

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --cloud-provider=aws
```